# Microsoft Excel 2010: Help making a Formula to up Values by a repeating pattern

Tags: excel, design-patterns, formula, repeat

I have a Spreadsheet, and inside this sheet contains a column with numbers, I want to make a formula that will go down that Column and do basically this.. Values: 1 will be 9.50. 2 will be 9.75. 3 will be 10.00. Ect going up to Value of 100? Is that possible for a Formula? I keep playing with it but can't really seem to get it down. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Column A: 1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
```

There is not a set amount to how many values are in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it supposing that column A has these values 1, 2 ...etc that your computing will be based on

```
=MIN(9.25+A1*0.25;100)*COUNT(A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In A2, enter the formula

```
=A1 + (9.5-A1)
```

then in the cell just below it (A3), enter

```
=A2+0.25
```

Assuming A1 is the top left. Copy the formula in A3, select the next 399 cells and paste. Then select A2 - A364 and copy. Then select B2 -xx364 and paste. xx is the last column with data. If you want, set the height of your first column to 0 to hide it.

Comment: There are multiple cells with 1 though, Like A1-7 May be 1, then A7-19 may be 2, ect.. Is there a way to check?

Comment: @Leaum So you need the first cell to go from whatever value it is to 9.5?

Comment: Yes, any cell containing the Value of 1 needs to be 9.5, any cell containing value 2, 9.75, any celling going up to value 100, needs to be changed by a .25 increase starting a 1:9.50

Comment: Ok, I see what you did there.. I don't think I made it clear enough, I don't need each cell going up by .25.. I need JUST by Value. If the value changes from 1 to 2, then it goes from 9.50 to 9.75. Get it?

Comment: You need it to increase by the given multiple of .25? So if the top column is 1, each row increases by .25, if it's 3, each row increases by .75, if it's 7, each row increases by 1.75?

Answer (score 0):

`=(A1-1)*0.25+9.5` where A1 contains any number you want